# GitLab Container Registry behind AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, gitlab, elastic-load-balancer

I currently have a GitLab instance setup behind an AWS load balancer (just to achieve HTTPS with my Amazon issued certificate).  I'm running nginx for the main GitLab service with the following settings (from `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`):

```
nginx['enable'] = true
nginx['listen_port'] = 80
nginx['listen_https'] = false
nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
    "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
    "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
}
```

I was trying to setup something similar for the Container Registry:

```
registry_nginx['enable'] = true
registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5000
registry_nginx['listen_https'] = false
registry_nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
  "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
  "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
}

gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "<REDACTED>"
gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = "5005"
```

However, whenever I try to login from my local machine via docker I just get `400 Bad Request`.  I believe the traffic is flowing as such:

`Local --|HTTPS:5005|--> AWS ELB --|HTTP:5000|--> registry nginx --|HTTP:5005|--> GitLab Container Registry`

Is that correct?  Could the issue be that the traffic hitting the container registry is in the form of HTTP and is thus being rejected by the container registry service?  If so, how would I correct my setup?  I'd like to use GitLab's container registry if possible, but using AWS ECR is also a possibility.

UPDATE: Tried logging in from the GitLab instance to the container registry and received a 400 error code stating that the request header or cookie is too large.  I'm trying to figure out how to update the nginx configuration for the container registry to allow for a larger request to be sent.

Comment: Here is related discussion: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/running-omnibus-gitlab-behind-an-aws-elb/4711

Answer (score 0):

here are my configurations that work for me with ALB that listen on port 5050 HTTPS and forwards to 5050 HTTP

```
nginx['listen_port'] = 80
nginx['listen_https'] = false
registry_external_url 'https://<subdomain>.<domain>:5050 
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = false
registry_nginx['listen_https'] = false
registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5050
```

to get to GitLab (not the registry) add another listener to ALB for HTTPS 443 to HTTP 80 and set

```
external_url 'https://<subdomain>.<domain>
```

Comment: reference https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#external-proxy-and-load-balancer-ssl-termination

Comment: why do you set gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = false ?